# Http request cycle - Apache

Tags: apache, http, web, webserver, appserver

How the apache http request lifecycle works ? Suppose if there are seperate web server and app server, what configurations files we need to have to route the browser request to app server via web server ?

Please help me in understanding the process of lifecycle how web and app server role.